# Element tags not showing colors in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vscode-extensions

I'm using Vue3 in vs code and the colors of the vue tags are white so I can't see what the colors of the tags are (template, script, style).

[Code sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GtWL.png)

```js
<script setup>
import { useStyleStore } from "@/stores/style.js";

const styleStore = useStyleStore();
</script>

<template>
  <div :class="{ dark: styleStore.darkMode }">
    <div class="bg-gray-50 dark:bg-slate-800 dark:text-slate-100">
      <slot />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>


</script>
```

I added the extension but it didn't work

Thank you for your help.

Comment: The two links point to the same image, are they supposed to be two different screenshots?

Comment: no,I am aware. I did this on purpose

Comment: Doesn't seem to be any point to include it twice. I edited your post and translated the image to text anyway. You should avoid posting code samples as images, always post as formatted text  so others can copy/paste easily. The original screenshot is still accessible from the link `Code Sample`. If you object to the edit you can of course roll it back or re-edit.

Comment: @moken in this case the code itself is not important.  It's not a problem that requires copy/pasting.  syntax highlighting problems are only really possible to show via screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the tags then you need to edit user settings.json.

VS code app -> Help (in top menu) -> Show all commands -> enter user settings -> select Open user setting (json).

If you haven't the "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" object in the settings file then add it otherwise edit it by adding your theme. Replace "Monokai" by the name of your theme and replace "#120a8a" by your preferred color

```
{
  // other settings objects
,
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Monokai]": {
      "textMateRules": [
        {
          // will affect all tags in your Vue file
          "name": "Other",
          "scope": "entity.name.tag.html",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#120a8a"
          }
        },
        {
          // will change <script> tag color
          "name": "Other",
          "scope": "entity.name.tag.html",
          "settings": {
            "foreground": "#eca03c"
          }
        },
      ]
    },
  },
 // other settings objects ...
}
```